# Is it posble create text on image with higher quality in .net

Tags: c#, .net, string, bitmap, drawing

I need to create some kind of graph in .net desktop application.
I use .Net Framework 4.7.2 and System.Drawing library.

The scenario looked like this.
In the console application I create a bitmap with X and Y axes and some simple lines and some text on those lines, nothing complicated.
After creating the bitmap, I save it as .bmp file.

The problem is that the letters and numbers I create are bad and look furry, I tried with different fonts and different settings but the result was always the same.

The picture looks like this:

[image: This is the bitmap that I created]

and under a magnifyer it looks like this:

[image]

This is my sample code:

```
        // create new bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(900, 700, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        g.Clear(Color.LightGray);
        
        // set attr
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;

        // draw X and Y axes
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(100, 100), new Point(100,600));
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(100, 600), new Point(800, 600));

        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);            
        Font font = new Font("Lucida Console", 14, FontStyle.Bold);

        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;

        // grid numbeers on x axis
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            g.DrawString(i.ToString(), font, brush, 100 * (i+1), 620);
        }

        // grid numbeers on y axis
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            g.DrawString(i.ToString(), font, brush, 70, 600 - (100 * i));
        }

        // label 1
        font = new Font("Lucida Console", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
        g.DrawString("Line - X axis", font, brush, 100, 650);

        // label 2
        font = new Font("Lucida Console", 32, FontStyle.Bold);
        g.DrawString("PORCO El.01", font, brush, 550, 150);

        // label 3
        font = new Font("Lucida Console", 24, FontStyle.Regular);
        g.DrawString("PORCO El.01", font, brush, 550, 200);

        // save as .bmp file
        bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(picturePath, "sample.bmp"));
```

Is it possible to get better text quality? Is there maybe another 3rd party library that can achieve better results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comment the two lines under `// set attr`. You are just drawing horizontal and vertical lines. So you don't need AntiAlias smoothing. And set `g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;`. See [Graphics.TextRenderingHint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) property. And dispose of the disposable graphics objects!

Comment: Maybe you want to increase the dpi settings from the screen default to something better?

Comment: Thanks @dr.null I wil try that. This is just a simple/sample code.